# Select randomly between 3 pictures

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hi i am trying to randomly select between 3 pictures 'BCloud1.png, BCloud2.png, BCloud3.png'
what is the best way to do this, i did try to add a `math.random(1, 3);` like :    `star4.imgpath = "BCloud .. math.random(1, 3); .. .png";`

but that's not working

```
-- select randomly between BCloud1.png, BCloud2.png, BCloud3.png

    local star4 = {}
    star4.imgpath = "BCloud1.png";
    star4.movementSpeed = 16000;
    table.insert(starTable, star4);
```

any easy fix for this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement has a little *syntactical error*. It should be:

```
star4.imgpath = "BCloud"..tostring(math.random(1, 3))..".png";
```

Comment: Create a function that does the generation and insertion of the star. Let's call it `myFunc()`. Then, add a `timer.performWithDelay( 2000, myFunc )`